# How to install nodejs 4.1.2 with HomeBrew

Tags: node.js, macos, ionic-framework, homebrew

I installed NodeJs with the following commands:

```
brew install node
```

It downloaded the version 5.5.0 of NodeJs.

I want the version **4.1.2** (for Ionic compatibility).

How to download this specific one?

I can't run `brew switch node 4.1.2` since I've never downloaded it before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Comment: Instead of homebrew, give nvm a try. https://github.com/creationix/nvm Allows easy switching between node versions, or easily updating node versions.

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest using **[nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown)** instead?

With nvm you can switch between node versions really easy:

```
nvm install 4.2
```

And you can install multiple versions of node and switch between them as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You can search available versions of node to install by running:

> brew search node

The closest version would be "node4-lts". To obtain that version, run:

> brew install homebrew/versions/node4-lts